# Cannot Access WCF members in Visual Studio 2010 -- Very Strange

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my web application I have added WCF service which is hosted on IIS. It was all working fine until the time windows has installed the update on the my development machine, and now Visual Studio 2010 does not recognize the service reference which I have added previously.
It is giving the error as 'Type  Service_Createuser is not defined'

Intellisence does not show the service reference either.

Below are the updates had installed on the machine :

1. KB2504637  Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
2. Security Update for Microsoft.Net Framework 4.5.1 (KB2901126)
3. Security Update for Microsoft.Net Framework 4.5.1 (KB2898869)

I have removed the service reference and added again but still the same problem.

Webservice was created using `.Net 3.5` and my web application is also set to .Net 3.5.

I have googled in but no luck!

Could someone please tell me what this updates has done. And how to resolve this problem.

Please let me know if you need more information. Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks
John

Comment: Hi Can someone shed some light on it please.